# File picker failed to filter and pick intent.setType("application/excel")

Tags: java, android, excel, android-intent

I am developing an android application for reading/writing excel files using apache poi. For picking a file from filesystem I used the following code

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/excel");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The line `intent.setType("application/excel");`is used to filter excel files.But android file manager doesnt pick any excel files.It remains in disabled stage. I checked this code by replacing `intent.setType("application/excel");`with `intent.setType("file/.mp3");` It works fine and it picks mp3 files. I also tried `intent.setType("file/.xls");` No luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938188/115145

Answer (score 7):

In this link you can refer a list of Microsoft Office MIME

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/4300670

```
Extension MIME Type
.doc      application/msword
.dot      application/msword

.docx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.docm     application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.dotm     application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12

.xls      application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlt      application/vnd.ms-excel
.xla      application/vnd.ms-excel

.xlsx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
.xlsm     application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
.xltm     application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
.xlam     application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb     application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12

.ppt      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pot      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pps      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.ppa      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.pptx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.potx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppsx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.ppam     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
.pptm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
.potm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
.ppsm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12

.mdb      application/vnd.ms-access
```

You can search for Excel files like below

```
private void searchExcelFile() {
        String[] mimeTypes = {"application/vnd.ms-excel" , "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"};
        Intent searchExcel = new Intent();
        searchExcel.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
        searchExcel.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //searchExcel.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            searchExcel.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
            if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
                searchExcel.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
            }
        } else {
            String mimeTypesStr = "";
            for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
                mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
            }
            searchExcel.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
        }

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(searchExcel,"Selecione Arquivo Excel"), EXCEL_IMPORTED);
    }
```

You can get the path like below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == EXCEL_IMPORTED) {


            if (data.getClipData() == null) {

                readExcelData(data.getData().getPath());
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Log.i("debinf cliinfo", "data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri().toString()" + data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri().toString());

                }
            }


        }
    } else {
        Log.i("debinf cliinfo", "resultCol NOT OK");
    }

}
```

There are two ways of reading Excel Files (maybe more), because of its extension (.xls and .xlsx) see the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047554/4300670

You can switch between the reading possibilities and write in a SQLiteDatabe like below:

```
private void readExcelData(String ExcelFilePath) {

    // HSSFWorkbook is for .xls
    // XSSFWorkbook is for .xlsx
    // Check the extension of the Excel file

    String[] path = ExcelFilePath.split(":");

    Workbook workbook = null;

    if (ExcelFilePath.endsWith(".xls")) {

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path[1]));
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: FileNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: Error reading InputStream " + e.getMessage());
        }

    } else if (ExcelFilePath.endsWith(".xlsx")) {

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path[1]));
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: FileNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: Error reading InputStream " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Log.i("debinf cliinf", "uri is " + ExcelFilePath.endsWith(".xls"));


    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Log.i("debinf cliinfo", "sheet is " + sheet);
    if (sheet == null) {
        return;
    }

    File dbfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+groupKeyIntent+"/"+"client.db");

    if (!dbfile.isFile()) {

        String Folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+groupKeyIntent+"/";
        new File(Folder).mkdirs();
        Log.i("debinf cliinfo", "rootFolder created: " + Folder);
        ClientDatabaseHelper createDatabaseHelper = new ClientDatabaseHelper(this,"client.db", Folder);
        clientListTable = createDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        clientRepository = new ClientRepository(clientListTable);
        //clientList = clientRepository.SearchAllClients();
        //mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    clientRepository.insertExcelToSqlite(sheet, groupKeyIntent);
    clientList = clientRepository.SearchAllClients();
    mClientListAdapter = new ClientListAdapter(clientList, clientRepository, groupNameIntent, groupKeyIntent, groupCreatorIntent);
    mClientList.setAdapter(mClientListAdapter);
    //mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using correct MIME type

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Thanks to CommonsWare

Comment: It did not work to me. I see the excel file, but I am not able to select it.